# LIN interface INH pin

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, can, interface, lin

What would happen if I pull down the INH pin of this [IC](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/ATA663211-LIN-Transceiver-Data-Sheet-DS20006191.pdf) to GND?

I am unable to understand what would happen if I pulled to GND or make it HIGH?

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What would happen if I pull down the INH pin of this IC to GND?*

It's an output (not an input) so I wouldn't go pulling it low in case the internal PMOS is trying to connect it to +Vsupply. From the data sheet page 8: -

> **The inhibit pin provides an internal switch toward the VS pin which is
> protected by temperature monitoring. If the device is in normal or
> Fail-Safe mode, the inhibit high-side switch is turned on. When the
> device is in Sleep mode, the inhibit switch is turned off, thus
> disabling the voltage regulator or other connected external devices.**

Comment: So, could you tell me what should I connect it to if I am not using? Unable to get clarity?

Comment: You don't need to connect it to anything if you don't use it @Newbie

Comment: Ok, shall I leave it open if I am not using?

Comment: Look on page 8 further down. It is used to enable an external microcontroller. If you don't need that functionality just leave it open (well, I'd connect it to a test point on a PCB just in case and, I might be tempted to connect it to a 10 kohm pull-down resistor too just in case you might want to see what is on the pin).

Comment: Shall I connect it to a 100k pull down to GND, if I am not using it? That wouldn't be a problem right?

Comment: It won't be a problem at all.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But could you please include this in your original answer. In your original answer, you mentioned you would not pull it low.

Comment: The pull-down resistor would not pull it low. In the answer I said don't pull it low and that means don't short it to ground. A pull-down resistor won't short it to ground.

Comment: But isn't 100k a pull-down resistor? But is 10k a pull-up resistor @Andyaka?

Comment: A 100 kohm resistor can be used as a pull-up or pull-down resistor. Ditto a 10 k resistor.